# MySQL needs to return specific records in result set within group by

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I need to construct a MySQL query where I can group results together based on one or more column values then return the **complete** record in that group that matches some criteria.

Take the table shown below as representative of my data:

```
| ID | NAME | Editor | Modified date | Type |
|  1 | doc1 | Smith  | 2012-01-01    | A    |
|  2 | doc2 | Smith  | 2012-03-03    | A    |
|  3 | doc1 | Jones  | 2012-10-10    | A    |
|  4 | doc1 | Scott  | 2011-01-01    | A    |
|  5 | doc2 | Boyd   | 2013-01-01    | A    |
|  6 | doc3 | Smith  | 2010-01-01    | B    |
|  7 | doc4 | Smith  | 2010-03-03    | B    |
|  8 | doc3 | Jones  | 2010-10-10    | B    |
|  9 | doc3 | Scott  | 2009-01-01    | B    |
| 10 | doc4 | Boyd   | 2011-01-01    | B    |
```

I want to return the most recently modified record relating to any document ie.

```
| ID | NAME | Editor | Modified date | Type |
|  3 | doc1 | Jones  | 2012-10-10    | A    |
|  5 | doc2 | Boyd   | 2013-01-01    | A    |
|  8 | doc3 | Jones  | 2010-10-10    | B    |
| 10 | doc4 | Boyd   | 2011-01-01    | B    |
```

Or the moste recently modified record relating to Type A

```
| ID | NAME | Editor | Modified date | Type |
|  3 | doc1 | Jones  | 2012-10-10    | A    |
|  5 | doc2 | Boyd   | 2013-01-01    | A    |
```

I have tried GROUP BY and HAVING and as far as I can tell they will not return the entire record.

Addendum: It may be that I need to alte the "most recent" qualifier to "prior to a given date"

Comment: The two results you want to return are mutually exclusive, no?

Comment: For the first result, did you try "group by NAME order by Modified_Date"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM tbl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(Modifed_date) as newestRecordDate, Editor
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY Editor
) as Newest
on tbl.Modifed_Date = Newest.NewestRecordDate
```

For by Type:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(Modifed_date) as newestRecordDate, Editor
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY Editor
) as Newest
ON tbl.Modifed_Date = Newest.NewestRecordDate
WHERE Type = 'A'
```

Note, the possible issue of Modified Date not including a time as well, and having more than one edit per day - ensure this record includes a time component as well.

Comment: looks good, will road test it a bit more..... have some pretty complicated scenarios

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the most recently modified rows, then you can use:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where `Modified date` = (select max(`Modified date`)
                         from yourtable t2
                         where t1.NAME = t2.NAME
                         group by `NAME`);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e90ab/6)

If you then want to return only those with `type='A'`, then the following will work:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where `Modified date` = (select max(`Modified date`)
                         from yourtable t2
                         where t1.NAME = t2.NAME
                         group by `NAME`)
  and type = 'A';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e90ab/8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**For first question:**

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.Editor, a.ModifiedDate, a.Type 
FROM tableName a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.name, MAX(b.ModifiedDate) ModifiedDate 
            FROM tableName b GROUP BY b.name
           ) b ON a.name = b.name AND a.ModifiedDate = b.ModifiedDate
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | NAME | EDITOR |                   MODIFIEDDATE | TYPE |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 | doc1 |  Jones | October, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    A |
|  5 | doc2 |   Boyd | January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    A |
|  8 | doc3 |  Jones | October, 10 2010 00:00:00+0000 |    B |
| 10 | doc4 |   Boyd | January, 01 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    B |
```

**And Filter by `Type='A'`:**

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.Editor, a.ModifiedDate, a.Type 
FROM tableName a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.name, MAX(b.ModifiedDate) ModifiedDate 
            FROM tableName b GROUP BY b.name
           ) b ON a.name = b.name AND a.ModifiedDate = b.ModifiedDate 
WHERE a.Type = 'A'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | NAME | EDITOR |                   MODIFIEDDATE | TYPE |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 | doc1 |  Jones | October, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    A |
|  5 | doc2 |   Boyd | January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    A |
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61290/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table group by NAME order by Modified_Date DESC;
select * from your_table where Type = 'A' group by NAME order by Modified_Date DESC;
```

Comment: Ok, yes that is valid. What if I wanted to change most recent to prior to 2013-01-01? In other words if simply using sort by des was not applicable?

Comment: If you do not want to use "order by" then, you can refer the answer given by "bluefeet" in this thread.  I came up with the same queries but I have given a vote for his answer for his live demo links.